# Change parameterised type List to instance of the Functor class

Tags: haskell, functor

I'm new with the Functor, so I have parameterised type List like this:

data List a = Empty | One a | Append (List a) (List a)

and the question asked me to change it into an instance of the Functor class in Haskell syntax. I'm struggling in define for each fmap

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You don't really have to *change* anything, so much as write a valid `instance` definition. Are you struggling with the syntax involved, or in how you need to define `fmap` for each variant of the list (`fmap f Empty`, `fmap f (One x)`, `fmap f (Append x y)`)?

Comment: @chepner yes, I'm struggling how to define fmap of each.

Comment: Start with `Empty`. Can you think of a good way to `fmap` on `Empty`? Once you have that, think of a way to `fmap` on `One`. Then `Append` is the slightly more complicated one. Remember, `fmap` should never change the *shape* of the data, so each constructor you match on should return a value using the same constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your structure again (a bit nicer formated):

```hs
data List a 
  = Empty 
  | One a 
  | Append (List a) (List a)
```

You are asked to define a *Functor-Instance* for that so let's start by pattern-matching on the 3 constructors:

```hs
instance Functor List where
  fmap f Empty = ...
  fmap f (One a) = ...
  fmap f (Append a b) = ...
```

---

in the `Empty` there is (aside from bottom-values like `undefined`, ...) really only one possibility - you have to return a `List a` - `Empty` is possible, for `One` you'd need one `a`-value (which you don't have) and for `Append` you'd need two `List`s again. Sure you could take `Append Empty Empty` but remember one of the *functor-laws* states `fmap id l === l` for all Lists l (meaning exactly the same - not Haskells `Eq`!) - so there is only one choice:

```hs
instance Functor List where
  fmap _ Empty = Empty
```

---

for `One` it's similar: you need `fmap id (One a) === One a` so the constructor is fixed and for the general case `fmap :: (a -> b) -> List a -> List b` you see that you have to use `f` on the wrapped `a`-value in `One`:

```hs
instance Functor List where
  fmap f (One a) = One (f a)
```

---

Finally for the `Append`-case. By now you should know that this needs to result in `Append (..) (..)` again (functor-law) and the two arguments to `Append` on the right-side needs to be `List b`. Now how to get `List b` when you have `List a`? If you look around: `fmap f :: List a -> List b` so you have a way to turn `List a`s (of which you have two in scope) into `List b`s (maybe not surprising as `Append` is recursive too) and again the *functor-laws* only let you one choice (why?):

```hs
instance Functor List where
  fmap f (Append a a') = Append (fmap f a) (fmap f a')
```

so you get:

```hs
instance Functor List where
  fmap _ Empty = Empty
  fmap f (One a) = One (f a)
  fmap f (Append a b) = Append (fmap f a) (fmap f b)
```

---

PS: Normally - not Homework - you could do:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}
module ... where

data List a 
  = Empty 
  | One a 
  | Append (List a) (List a)
  deriving Functor
```

and the GHC will figure this out for you ;)